# apk installation via my application

Tags: android

i get parse error once i use my function below

```
public void installFile()
{
    String path = "/data/data/com.utsc.smartdictate/";
    String filename = "smartdictate.apk";
    File file = new File(path + filename);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

i tried pulling the apk file from the emulator and tried installing it, to test if the file was corrupted or not, however it installed! so i dont know why it is failing.

EDIT: i have "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" permission added in the manifest

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Also, what are the permissions of the apk file?

Comment: By permissions, he means the PERMISSIONs declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: i have "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" permission

Comment: You cannot hold `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` -- that is only for firmware.

Comment: Actually, I meant the Unix permissions of the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the file is not readable by the installer. Files in your application-local file store are not readable by other processes by default. You will need to either store the file on external storage, or create your file use `openFileOutput()` and `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`, or create a content provider to serve that file.

Also:

- Never hardwire a path. Use `getFilesDir()` to get the root of your application-local file store
- Do not store files in `/data/data/com.utsc.smartdictate/`, but in `/data/data/com.utsc.smartdictate/files`, which is what you will get from `getFilesDir()`
- Do not concatenate strings to get a complete path -- use the proper `File` constructor instead

Comment: i moved my download to sdcard and it worked! its a permission problem. thank you

Comment: after installing the "update" package when i click open the installer just close, and nothing happen.

Comment: Can you show us the logs from logcat? It should tell you what's happening when you click that app.

Comment: @Viren, after we installed an app, it will prompt us the installation is completed, and we have two options, one is Open and the other is done. tapping Open does nothing.